# How to read a JSON file from Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I have flare.json file in my `Content` folder in an ASP.NET MVC project. And I'm trying to read it like this from razor:

```
d3.json("Content/flare.json", function (error, flare) {
```

I want to load json like this example : 
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

But I couldn't load no matter what I have tried. Can you tell me how I can read that JSON file? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: did you pick that name just so you could go about and ask alot of random JSON questions? +1 if not

Comment: @JamesP it doesn't work. it goes to `http://localhost:12345/Controller/~/Content/flare.json`

Comment: So did you try with just `"/Content/flare.json"`?

Comment: @Arg0n's comment worked. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesP that would only work if you used Razor to construct the URL, e.g. using a HTML helper.